# Multiple actions provided from the API for in GCP's DLP does not work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

**Goal**: Read CSV file from Cloud Storage bucket and publish the findings to Pub/Sub and write findings to BigQuery

**Issue**: I am able to do this using the Console, but when I try to do it using the API, only of the actions work. Following is a sample from my code:

```
'actions': [{
          'pub_sub': {
              'topic':
                  'projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_id}'.format(
                      project_id=PROJECT_ID, topic_id=PUB_SUB_TOPIC)
          },
          
        'save_findings': {
            "output_config": {
                "table": {
                    "project_id": PROJECT_ID,
                    "dataset_id": DATASET_ID,
                    "table_id": TABLE_ID
               
                }
            }
        }
      }]
```

In the above code, only the option of publishing to BigQuery will work as it is written later. I came across the documentation given at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/InspectJobConfig#action), which says *'Union field action can be only one of the following'*

**Questions**:
Is my understanding correct, that using the API only one of the actions is possible (write to the database or publish to pub/sub etc)?

If Yes, is there going to be support for multiple actions using the APIs similar to the console?

**Appendix**: PFA screenshot of the configuration of a DLP job using the console having multiple actions[image]

Comment: This isn't valid JSON - are you using a templating framework to generate this? Would be useful to include that as a tag, if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objects are not nested quite right.

```
"actions": [
  {
    "pubSub": {
      "topic": "mytopic"
    }
  },
  {
    "saveFindings": {
      "outputConfig": {
        "outputSchema": "BIG_QUERY_COLUMNS",
        "table": {
          "datasetId": "",
          "tableId": "",
          "projectId": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/InspectJobConfig#action), it is a documented limitation for the REST API. It mentions. In addition, this limitation is also found at in the RPC side of the Rest API, [here](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rpc/google.privacy.dlp.v2#action). Both states:

> ***action can be only one of the following***

However, I would suggest you to change your script in order to make *two* *calls* to ***create_dlp_job()*** method, each one containing one action at a time in the variable with the REST.

Finally, you could also open a Feature Request within the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).